# Функция, которая создает новую уникальную группу и отправляет ссылку-приглашение пользователю (aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как сделать функцию для телеграмм-бота, которая создает новую уникальную группу и отправляет ссылку-приглашение пользователю?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])
async def cmd_test(message: Message):
    chat_id = "-100000000000"
    expire_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
    link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(chat_id, expire_date.timestamp, 1)

    print(link.invite_link)
```

Здесь у меня есть чат с 'chat_id', который был создан вручную.

ГЛАВНЫЙ ВОПРОС: Как генерировать новые чаты и отправлять ссылку приглашение обратно пользователю? То есть, **Я не понимаю как сделать так что бы бот сам создавал чат и присылал инвайт ссылку обратно пользователю, что бы я мог создавать сколько угодно таких групп (или чатов) и если нужно, то удалял их тоже с помощью бота**

Comment: А что у вас не получается?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Зонтик Я не понимаю как сделать так что бы бот сам создавал чат и присылал инвайт ссылку обратно пользователю, что бы я мог создавать сколько угодно таких групп (или чатов) и если нужно, то удалял их тоже с помощью бота

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh пожалуйста, добавьте текст вашего комментария в вопрос =).

Comment: @Зонтик добавил, надеюсь теперь мой вопрос более понятен)